# Kendo grid generate dynamic html in a column based on column value?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid,where i have a requirement to generate dynamic HTML based on value of a column which will be returned by another function.I have the following code

```js
$("#divGenerateLogin_kendogrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: data,
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                sortable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                pageable: {
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                filterable: true,
                // selectable: true ,
                // dataBound: onDataBound,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "StudentName",
                        title: "Student Name",
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Class",
                        title: "Class",
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Login",
                        template: "#: LoginColHtml(IsLoginAvilable==1) #"   
                    }

                ]
            });
            
            
            
function LoginColHtml(isLoginAvilable) {

            var html = "";
            if (isLoginAvilable == true) {
                html = "<button type='button' class='btn-ressetpwd'><i class='fa fa-key'></i> reset password</button>";
            } else {
                html = "<button type='button' class='btn-generatelogin'><i class='fa fa-user'></i> generate login</button>";
            }
            // "<div>#: (IsGuardianLoginAvilable==1) #</div>";
            return html;

        }
```

Instead of returning  actual html  in a column its returning  as a string. How can i add actual HTML to the column instead of as a string ?

FYI
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this and it worked

```js
{
     title: "Guardian Login",
     template: "#= LoginColHtml(IsLoginAvilable==1) #"     
}
```